# python Tronado not supporting streaming huge data

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I have requirement to stream huge oracle record set in Python rest API. I am running flask on tornado server. when I use tornado streaming dosent work, whereas on flask native server(werkzeung)  it works perfectly. can anyone help me tornado support streaming or not?
Here is a small sample of code just trying to stream by using yield.

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen, httpclient
import asyncio, json, time

class basicReuqestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Helow World!")

class staticReuqestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class StreamingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("starting ....")
        def stream():
            a = 1
            for i in range(100):
                a = a+i
                print(i)
                print(json.dumps(i))
                yield json.dumps(i)
        self.write(stream())
        self.write("closing...")
        self.finish()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", basicReuqestHandler),
        (r"/myPage",staticReuqestHandler ),
        (r"/StreamTest", StreamingHandler),
    ])
    app.listen(7000)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Show us some code, please...

Comment: Depending on how you read/process the source data you might be blocking Tornado's IOLoop.

Comment: Please find the sample code. I am unable to stream the response, the range I gave as an example just consider that is the generator like db cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake, so answering to my question here to help anyone having similar issue.
here is the code:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen, httpclient
import asyncio, json, time

class basicReuqestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Helow World!")

class staticReuqestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class StreamingHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("starting ....")
        def stream():
            for i in range(100):
                print(i)
                print(json.dumps(i))
                self.write(json.dumps(i))
                yield self.flush()
        self.write("closing...")
        self.finish()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", basicReuqestHandler),
        (r"/myPage",staticReuqestHandler ),
        (r"/StreamTest", StreamingHandler),
    ])
    app.listen(7000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```